# Can't SFTP from an Azure VM

Tags: azure, sftp

Sorry to bother you if this question was answered elsewhere, since I wasn't able to find that ;-)

I have an Azure VM running Windows 2016. I installed about 3 different (S)FTP clients, but none of them was able to connect to a remote (non-Azure) SFTP server from a supplier. My client (also non-Azure) is also very successful when it comes to connecting.
I have disabled the Firewall in Windows Server 2016 AND made an inbound security rule in Azure, allowing everything from everywhere. No luck.

When searching for answers, I found a lot of topics about running a SFTP server in Azure, which I'm not doing, or when using FTPS (instead of SFTP). Hope you guys can help me out on what I might need to do / where to look.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I noticed this question was still open. Just wanted to let you know that the cause of my issue was caused by the party that hosted the SFTP environment: they blacklisted my IP. Since it was a fresh new server from the Azure pool, I think the IP address was used for some other purposes or in another region before or something. They unlisted me and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot this kind of issue, we need to check if this is a network level issue or application level issue.

To check if the client has a valid path to the destination server, please try to use a tool called [Port Query](https://www.microsoft.com/en-hk/download/details.aspx?id=24009) on the client to verify if the service port is reachable from the client.

If the port is unreachable, it means that something between the server and client blocks this connection. Please check the firewalls between them. (Including the local firewall of the client and server)

If the port is reachable from the client, then the server should receive the request from the client and your should troubleshoot this issue on application level. Please check if there is related log on the server or client side.